# Animation object goes behind the view

Tags: android

The app is basically a snake and ladder type app, I roll the dice and expect the player piece to animate(translate) to the resultant box.
But that's not happening, the piece just hides behind the other boxes as soon as it leaves the parent box, this is how: http://tinypic.com/r/a4omja/9
I was unable to figure out the reason.

Here's the code:

```
public void move(final int frombox, final int tobox){
        /*Condition for first roll, it's direct, haven't coded it's animation yet */
        if(box0.indexOfChild(playerPiece[turnInt])!=-1) {
            box0.removeView(playerPiece[turnInt]);
            boxes[tobox].addView(playerPiece[turnInt]);
        }
        else {
            animate(playerPiece[turnInt], frombox, tobox);
        }
    }

    private void animate(View v,final int frombox, final int tobox) {
        AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();

        ObjectAnimator y = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v,
                "translationY",v.getY(), boxes[tobox].getY());

        ObjectAnimator x = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v,
                "translationX", v.getX(), boxes[tobox].getX());

        animSetXY.playTogether(x, y);
        //animSetXY.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animSetXY.setDuration(1000);
        animSetXY.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                boxes[frombox].removeView(playerPiece[turnInt]);
                Log.i("Check", "Removed from " + frombox);
                boxes[tobox].addView(playerPiece[turnInt]);
                Log.i("Check", "Added to " + tobox);
                playerPiece[turnInt].clearAnimation();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
        });
        animSetXY.start();
    }
```

The log messages do show the view being added and removed from correct places, but it's never visible after the first animation (i.e after the second roll, because 1st roll is direct)

Answer (score 0):

To bring it to front you should use `bringToFront()` method

```
v.bringToFront();
```

Comment: (1) It should be playerPiece[turnInt].bringToFront() , 
AnimSet doesn't have that method.
(2) Doesn't help, tried it at 3 places but the view still remains behind.

Comment: @Abhijeet yes. it was mistaken , it should be called upon the view that you want to bring to front.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out but it's not the correct solution unfortunately, the view still remains behind

Comment: @Abhijeet did you figure it out?  post your own answer , others will learn from that , 
 :) cheers (:

Comment: No, I mean I figured out it should be called on view to bring to front, not the answer :)

Comment: when did you called `bringToFront()` ? it should be after starting animation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158744/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-irony-stack).